# Disable autoopen select results when delete tag in select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have multiple select using select2. How can I disable autoopen select's results when i remove tag from it?

I have the same code as at http://select2.github.io/examples.html

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

If I select some option, and after that i want to remove it, i click on the close button in the tag. When the option is removed, select's result appears. How can I remove some option without autoopen options list?

Comment: Please provide HTML, JS and CSS. It is hard to tell without looking into the code

Comment: please give a demo scripts.

Comment: Here is class CSS that manage this things